# Value was not retained outside of a function

Tags: c, string, function, malloc

I'm writing a program that should get its inputs from a text file by using input redirection in a function called GetInput. (The text file contains 10 words.) The code should then be able to print the contents of ListWord in the Print function.

This is what I have so far.
I keep on getting errors while trying to run this code. I tried to remove * before ListWord and the code works but it does not retain the word (string) that was stored in it. But removing * before ListWord does not make sense to me. What am I doing wrong?

```
void GetInput( char** ListWord)       
{
    int i=0;
    char word[30]; //each word may contain 30 letters
    *ListWord = malloc(sizeof(char*)*10); //there are 10 words that needs to be allocated

    while(scanf("%s", word)==1) //Get Input from file redirection
    {
        *ListWord[i]= (char *)malloc(30+1);
        printf("%s\n", word); //for checking
        strcpy(*ListWord[i], word);
        printf("%s\n", *ListWord[i]); //for checking
        i++;
    }

}

void Print(char *ListWord)
{
    //print ListWord
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", ListWord[i]);
    }
}

int  main()
{
  char * ListWord; 

  GetInput(&ListWord); 
  printf("%s\n", ListWord[0]);
  Print(ListWord);

  free(ListWord);

  return 0;
}
```

(Note: This is a homework. Thank you and sorry if it's unclear)

Comment: As a starter, `char * ListWord;` should be actually `char ** ListWord;` and if you want to pass this as an argument to function (and not get returned from function), argument type should be `char ***`. `free` would be complex.

Comment: Looks like you're passing `by value` and not `by reference`

Comment: @MisterMister If it is known that there are exactly 10 words then why did not you just declare a two-dimensional array of 10 character arrays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to [*operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) the expression `*ListWord[i]` doesn't do what you think it does. In fact you should be getting errors or warnings from the code you have.

The compiler thinks that `*ListWord[i]` means `*(ListWord[i])`, which is not right. You need to use `(*ListWord)[i]`.

---

Unfortunately that's only the start of your problems. A bigger problem is that the pointer you pass to the function `GetInput` is not a pointer to what could become an array of strings, but a pointer to a single string.

For a dynamic allocated array of strings, you need a pointer to a pointer to begin with, and then emulate pass-by-reference on that, i.e. you need to become a *three star programmer* which is something you should avoid.

Instead of trying to pass in the array to be allocated as an argument, have the `GetInput` *return* the array instead. Something like

```
char **GetInput(void)
{
    // Allocate ten pointers to char, each initialized to NULL
    char **ListWords = calloc(10, sizeof(char *));
    if (ListWords == NULL)
        return NULL;

    char word[31];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10 && scanf("%30s", word) == 1; ++i)
    {
        ListWords[i] = strdup(word);
    }

    return ListWords;
}
```

The above code adds some security checks, so you will not go out of bounds of either the temporary array you read into, or the `ListWords` array. It also makes sure the `ListWords` array is initialized, so if you read less then 10 words, then the remaining pointers will be `NULL`.

---

Of course you need to change your `main` function accordingly, and also your `Print` function, because now it only takes a single string as argument, not an array of strings. You also of course need to `free` every single string in the array because freeing the array.